# Quiz Game Score

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am currently creating a quiz game wherein the questions were stored in the database, there is also a hall of fame which ranked the player scores. My question is how can I add the value of score in the database if the answer is correct?
For example if the answer is correct, my score in the database will also increased by one. I try to use update set score but the problem is setting the score to specific number is not okay, it should just increase by 1 every correct answer. Thank you. Im using VB.NET and MySQL

Comment: update the database and change the value. Where's your code?

Comment: Please read [ask] and perhaps visit the [help].  The purpose of the site is to help with code that doesnt work quite right, not provide tutorials or from scratch design services.  If you dont even know where to start, do [some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).  As is, this is too broad.  (Hint: a DB does not need to be updated upon every micro step an app takes - you can use a *variable*)

Answer (score 0):

For example,your **SCORE COLUMN** is the 2nd column in the database and it's data type is **int**.. then u can just populate a datatable and on every right answer,insertt the value of the table's 2nd row + 1..

An example would look like this :

```
   Dim con as new Mysqlconnection =connectionstring
   Dim cmd as new mysql command("select * from table",con)

   Dim table as new datatable

   Dim adapter as new mysqldataadapter

    adapter.fill(table)

    dim cmd2 as new mysqlcommand("Insert into tablename(score) value(@score)",con)

  cmd.parameters.add("@score",mysqldbtype.int).value= table.rows(0)(1) + 1
```

As mentioned in comments,use a variable.. Then at the very end,insert the variable value in the db

Comment: If you are after rep, answering bad questions which are DVd wont get you there.  Most will get deleted; if the user doesnt improve their Qs and continue to get DVs which will ban them.  Many will rage quit and all your points go with them (the `User Removed` in rep history).  There are other issues, but mainly answering bad questions encourages bad users to ask more bad questions which hurts the site.  If you are after rep, you can get to 2000 very quickly by editing posts (formatting, tags in titles etc) which *improves* the site.